# ClassCastException Double to Float

Tags: java, android, casting

For some reason, this code is throwing a `ClassCastException`, telling me that I cannot cast a Double to a Float. The exception emanates from the first line of code below. `mapData.speeds` is an `ArrayList<Float>`.
Where is the Double?

```
float spd = mapData.speeds.get(focusPointIndex);
spd = (spd * 3600/1609.34);
```

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at net.taptools.android.trailtracker.ResultsMapViewingFragment$4.onMapLongClick(ResultsMapViewingFragment.java:224)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$5.onMapLongClick(Unknown Source)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.k$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IOnMapLongClickListener$Stub$Proxy.onMapLongClick(IOnMapLongClickListener.java:93)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at maps.i.s.a(Unknown Source)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at maps.y.v.d(Unknown Source)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at maps.y.bf.onLongPress(Unknown Source)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at maps.d.v.onLongPress(Unknown Source)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at maps.d.h.c(Unknown Source)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at maps.d.h.c(Unknown Source)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at maps.d.j.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-31 01:00:51.008: E/AndroidRuntime(17778):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## --edit--

I think I have found what has caused the error, but still do not know why it is occurring, or how to fix it. I am parsing the mapData Object out of JSON, and because it contains many ArrayLists of various types, I created a method that will parse a JSONArray into and ArrayList of a designated type. Here is the method.

```
private <T> ArrayList<T> JSONArrayToList(JSONArray jsonArr){
        ArrayList<T> arrList = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArr.length(); i++){
            try {
                arrList.add((T)jsonArr.get(i));
            } catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        return arrList;
    }
```

Comment: Is `spd` declared to be a `float` or a `Float`? And are you absolutely sure that the error is not from the second line?

Comment: Do you have any non-standard settings for error messages? What version of Java are you compiling with?

Comment: It wouldn't matter if it's a float or the wrapper class, Java will auto-unbox it

Comment: no, I haven't messed with the error message settings. I am compiling with 1.6.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that your code actually declares `spd` to be a `Float` (rather than a `float`). I'm also guessing that the exception is from the second line. Try changing the second line to:

```
spd = (spd * 3600 / 1609.34f);
```

That will make the right side a `float` rather than a `double`. Floating point literals in Java are `double` unless they end in `f` or `F`.

<strike>If my guesses are accurate, the exception is being caused by Java autoboxing the `double`-valued expression to a `Double` and then trying to cast it to a `Float` in order to assign it to variable `spd`.</strike>

After playing around a bit, I find that I cannot duplicate your error message. Your code won't even compile; the compiler complains "error: possible loss of precision" on the second line. So now I have another guess: you've suppressed that error message (or set it to be a warning instead of an error and are ignoring it).

Comment: I don't think you can suppress *that* error message ("loss of precision").  The JLS says that assigning `double` to `float` without a typecast is illegal code, and any compiler that allowed you to do that would not be compliant.

Comment: spd really was, and is, a primitive. I tried adding the 'f', but to no avail. I received the same error. I do not even know how to suppress errors or set an error as a warning, and thus doubt that I did.

Comment: @brainmurphy1 - Can you post the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @brainmurphy1 - Do you get the same exception when you run on a non-obfuscated version of your code?

Comment: non obfuscated? My code was copied from Eclipse right onto this page. If you are referring to the google maps android API v2 stuff, how would I 'unobfuscate' it?

Comment: @brainmurphy1 - I mean that the stack trace shows that the code that is running has been through ProGuard (which happens when you export your app for publication). But perhaps that's just the google maps stuff. If so, disregard my comment. Are you running this on a device or the emulator?

Comment: I am running on a device. I haven't messed around with the ProGuard stuff at all, so my configuration is default -- whatever that may be. The google maps android api v2 actually doesn't work on the emulator as far as my research has shown.

Answer (score 2):

If `mapData.speeds` is really declared as an `ArrayList<Float>` then the only way you can get a class cast exception like that is if you have suppressed / ignored some warnings about unsafe conversions.  (Either in the code that sets the  `speed` attribute or the code that puts values into the list.)

The class cast will be happening because your code is actually equivalent to this:

```
Float tmp = (Float) (mapData.speeds.get(focusPointIndex));
float spd = tmp.floatValue();
```

and the actual (erased) signature of `mapData.speeds.get` is `Object get(int)`.

Normally (i.e. if you don't suppress the warnings) the compiler will tell you if you do something that *would* result in a `Double` being added to an `ArrayList<Float>`.  However, if you ignore those warnings you can end up with a `Double` in what is supposed to be an `ArrayList<Float>`.  If that happens, you will get a class cast exception when you use the result of the `get` as a `float`.

Comment: I didn't ignore any warnings as far as I know, so I don't think my problem meets the criteria of your solution.

Comment: OK.  So try this.  `Object spd = mapData.speeds.get(focusPointIndex);  System.out.println(spd.getClass());`  I bet it outputs `java.lang.Double`.

Comment: yes! It is. How can that be? It is declared as "public ArrayList<Float> speeds;" in the MapData class.

Answer (score 0):

Change `3600/1609.34` to `3600f / 1609.34f`

If you use a decimal number in your code it will be inferred as a type double.  Include an F at the end of the number to tell the compiler it's a float not a double.

For best practice, make a habit of always ending your decimal constants with a D or F (Double or Float).
It shouldn't seem like overkill considering that Java makes you type your brains out just to write the simplest flow.

Comment: I added the f's. Nothing changed. Thanks though